# SyncTeX with gedit and Evince

Tags: gedit, evince, latex

In Oneiric gedit [includes support for SyncTeX](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/gedit-plugins) and Evince has supported it since 2.32 (Oneiric includes Evince 3.2.0). How do I use SyncTeX with gedit and Evince? I have compiled with the `-synctex=1` option but nothing happens when I try to backward/inverse search by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the document in Evince.

Comment: Maybe http://www.benwhale.com/blog/2011/06/26/synctex-gedit-evince/ is of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution today, and here is how it works:

1. Download `gedit-plugins`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
   ```
2. Go to Gedit preferences and enable the plugin. Restart Gedit.
3. Open a `.tex` file and open its `.pdf` output in Evince. The two files must be in the same folder.
4. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left click at any desired location in Evince. This will highlight the current row in Gedit.

Hope that helps!

---

Things I couldn't get working yet:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click in Gedit does focus the window of Evince, but does not highlight anything.

Things I haven't tested yet:

- Using Synctex with a document consisting of multiple files.

Comment: Forward search works for me neither.

Comment: Ctrl+left click in Gedit now (Ubuntu 18.04) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, it works in the direct and reverse form if you write  \synctex=1 in the second line of tex file!!