# How to use gedit-latex-plugin?

Tags: 11.10, gedit, latex

I have installed the packages `texlive` and `gedit-latex-plugin`.  I see syntax highlighting for .tex files, but I don't get any extra stuff in my gedit menus or toolbars for latex -> pdf like I expected to see, and there isn't anything resembling a latex plugin there to enable in the edit -> preferences -> plugins dialog.  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gedit-latex in ubuntu repos works only with gedit-2.x, however ubuntu 11.10 comes with more recent gedit-3.x. Try to use this one https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/gedit-latex-plugin/3.3.1-1~oneiric1

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It has to do with the fact that ubuntu 11.10 comes with a newer version of gedit, which doesn't support the `gedit-latex-plugin` (version 0.2.0) that is currently in the ubuntu repositories.

A new version of `gedit-latex-plugin` is currently under development [here (in lauchpad)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-latex-plugin/)

Here are some options:

- You could try to run the present unstable version of the plugin. This was constantly segfaulting on my machine, so I moved on...
- You could try a standalone editor, for instance **latexila** is a great editor. It doesn't, however, support the use of snippets (which is a deal-breaker for me). If snippets aren't that important to you, try it out:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install latexila
  ```
- I ended up using the *external tools* plugin for gedit. There's a nice post about this option [here](http://www.benwhale.com/blog/2011/06/26/synctex-gedit-evince/). A quick how to:

  1. Within gedit, go to *edit*  >  *preferences*  >  *plugins*  and scroll down to the *external tools* plugin and make sure its box is ticked.
  2. Close the Preferences dialog and go to *tools*  >  *manage external tools*
  3. Each tool is a just shell script. You can use several variables as explained [here](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools). For example, my Latex-to-PDF tool looks like:

     ```
     #!/bin/sh

     filename=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
     shortname=`echo $filename | sed 's/\(.*\)\.tex$/\1/'`

     latex -interaction batchmode -src $filename
     bibtex $shortname
     makeindex $shortname
     latex -interaction batchmode -src $filename
     latex -synctex=1 -interaction batchmode -src $filename
     dvips -t a4 $shortname.dvi
     ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dOptimize=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true $shortname.ps
     evince $shortname.pdf
     ```

     A drawback is that this does not support larger "projects", it only compiles the file that is currently being edited.

*Tip* Check out [this post on SyncTex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68015/synctex-with-gedit-and-evince) for forward and backward search between gedit and evince, it's great!